# how to pass a form as a parameter?

Tags: c#

First I know there are already answer for this question but most solution seems complicated for nothing.

**Situation :**

I have a form called frm1. I want to pass it as parameter

```
myfunc(ref frm1)
```

I would then do

```
private void myfunc(ref Form frm1)

It says : frm1 is a type but is used as a variable.
```

My reason for doing this is because depending on choice I pass my form to one of either two functions which fills it differently.

**Problem :**

However I cannot pass as argument my form. However I can pass other controls like button in the same way. How can I do this simply with the form, without interface etc...

Comment: Form is a class. Your class is probably called Form1. 
Change the name from Form -> Form1 and it might work (if not post more code)

Comment: Why are you using `ref`? You probably don't need it.

Comment: If he has large images (for example) in his form i'd use a ref.

Comment: @Blaatz0r Form is a reference type, so nothing is copied but the reference when it's passed as a parameter.

Comment: Is the method in the Form class?  If so, just reference the form using `this`

Comment: thanks!! what I did and works fine now!!

Comment: @Rik. Didnt know form was passed by ref. I do know arrays and such are passed by ref but that seems logical.

Comment: @Blaatz0r It's not technically pass-by-reference; it's a reference that's passed-by-value: http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: Lol nice that you take a jon skeet example. That guy is a magician

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is something wrong with the way you are passing the parameter in. Are you definitely passing in the instance and not the type?

Here's a working example.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Name = "form";

        Form f = this;

        doSomethingWithForm(f);
    }

    private void doSomethingWithForm(Form f)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! passing this instead of the name of the Form worked!! Probably because the name of the form is also used by default as the class name?

Comment: You don't need to pass any parameter.  Just reference `this` inside the method.

Comment: I did not know the context in which the method was going to be used so I added a parameter just in case it was not going to reside in the same class. The name you would need to pass in would be a variable referencing a particular instance of Form1. Have a look in program.cs in your project. There you will be able to see the instance of form1 being made.

Answer (score 0):

I have created one function. I think it will help you. I am using this in my practice.

-->function below:

```
public void showForm(Form _form, Form _main) {
if (_main != null)
{
if (_main.ActiveMdiChild != null)
{
    _main.ActiveMdiChild.Close();
}
_form.MdiParent = _main;
_form.Activate();
_form.Show();
}
else
{
_form.Activate();
_form.ShowDialog();
}
```

-->how to use it:

```
objLib.showForm(new frmMain(), null);
```

OR

```
objLib.showForm(new frmNewspaper(), this);
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I will add to kenjara's answer.

```
// For example: change color of the form - from some other method 
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChS = new ChangeSomething();
    ChS.ChangeBackColor(this);
}


public class ChangeSomething
{
    public void ChangeBackColor(Form form)
    {
        form.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        return;
    }
}
```

Tested VS2022 / .NET4.8 / Windows Forms